# Error when using multiple threads to write to db2 in python

Tags: python, multithreading, db2

I am using ibm_db python library to insert data into db2.
Everything worked fine while there was a single thread. As soon as I started to use multiple threads to speed up the writing to db2, I started getting an error:

> Exception: [IBM][CLI Driver] SQL0902C  A system error occurred.
>   Subsequent SQL statements cannot be processed. IBM software support
>   reason code: "".  SQLSTATE=58005 SQLCODE=-902

My code with a single thread was something like this:

```
def process_user(user):
   ....
   sqlstr = "insert into ..."
   ibm_db.exec_immediate(db2conn, sqlstr)
   return 1 

for user in users:
   n += process_user(user)
```

My code using multiple threads was:

```
from multiprocessing import Pool
def process_user(user):
   ....
   sqlstr = "insert into ..."
   ibm_db.exec_immediate(db2conn, sqlstr)
   return 1 


pool = Pool(20)
nusers = len(pool.map(process_user, users))
```

My question is what is the correct way to use multiple threads to insert data into db2?

Comment: It looks like maybe you're sharing one `db2conn` for all threads.  Have you tried giving each thread its own connection?

Comment: create pconnection for every thread and check if database hasn't any restriction(number of connections)

Comment: @user212514 Yes, I am sharing a single db2conn for all threads. I thought it can support multithreading, but it looks from your comments it doesn't.  Thanks, will try to give each thread its own connection.

Comment: @ValeriySolovyov Thanks, will do this. It seems that a single connection doesn't support multithreading.